# Get file from directory with max date in file name

Tags: c#, linq, directory

I need get file with max date in file name.

Example of file: `zipFiles_2013-04-09_17-04-37.zip`

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath);
```

I can get only latestValue date. How can I get FullName or Name?

```
DateTime latestValue;
di.GetFiles().Max(x => DateTime.TryParseExact(GetFileNameDate(x.FullName), "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out latestValue));
```

Answer (score 3):

Order files by their names with `OrderByDescending`. And then take first one from result:

```
var latestFile = di.GetFiles()
                   .OrderByDescending(f => GetDateFromFileName(f.FullName))
                   .First();
```

Here `GetDateFromFileName` is a method which parses `DateTime` from file name. Something like this:

```
private DateTime GetDateFromFileName(string fileName)
{
   DateTime date;
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(GetFileNameDate(fileName), 
         "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
      return date;
   // default value if date cannot be parsed (you can use nullable DateTime also)
   return DateTime.MinValue;
};
```

You can also use [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) (available from NuGet) [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) method:

```
var latestFile = di.GetFiles().MaxBy(f => GetDateFromFileName(f.FullName));
```